# Eclipse Command Line Arguments Giving Exception

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]I am trying to use the "Program Arguments" field in Eclipse (using java, on a mac), but whenever I enter an argument, it treats the argument like a file.  I'm getting the same error no matter what.  For example, if I input AL into the command line, I get the following error:

```
I/O exception while reading: ......./AL (No such file or directory)
```

I'm assuming I didn't set something up right and I was wondering how to set the command line up?  I have made sure that I have the correct file, the correct method, and the pathway (the ....'s) is valid.  Not really sure why this isn't working and having a hard time finding answers online.

EDIT: I added a picture of the full program and output that I am getting.  For the arguments I put an "a" followed by a return key and a "b".

Comment: I've never seen a `/` used for arguments to the JVM. Do you mean to use `-al`?

Comment: no, that is the path to the file, and it is correct but it is adding my argument to the end of the path

Comment: can you provide screen shot of the run configurations of eclipse. Also once you run eclipse issues a consolidated command that you can copy and check. I suspect you have configured your classpath or path variables incorrectly

Comment: The 'Program Arguments' section of the Run Configuration contains arguments that are passed to your program. It is up to your code to deal with these. Show us what you are specifying in the Program Arguments and how your code is handling them.